# mounting storage devices using Openstore

Tags: c++, windows, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I am very new to c++ and was hoping someone could fill in the blanks on mounting a storage card. I am trying to mount my storage card under windows mobile. OpenStore might be working because I am not getting a error, but I am still trying to figure out the syntax for OpenPartition, MountPartition and GetStoreInfo. If someone could give me an example it would really help.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <storemgr.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain( int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[] )
{
    STOREINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cbSize = sizeof( STOREINFO );
    HANDLE hDsk;
    HANDLE Findpart;
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    DWORD Count = 600;
    WCHAR szDisk[] = L"DSK2:";

    hDsk = OpenStore(szDisk);

    HANDLE hPartition = OpenPartition(hDsk, TEXT("Part00"));

    MountPartition(hPartition);

    if(hDsk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        printf("Error opening store");

    if (!GetStoreInfo(hDsk, &si))
        printf("Error getting info");

    if(!DismountStore(hDsk)) 
        printf("Error Dismounting");

    if(!FormatStore(hDsk)) 
        printf("Error Formatting");

    CloseHandle(hDsk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here, an excerpt from some quick test project. Hope, it helps.

```
   HANDLE hStore, hPartSearch, hPart;
   STOREINFO StoreInfo;
   PARTINFO PartInfo[3];
   DWORD error;
   BOOL bRes;

   hStore = OpenStore(L"DSK1:");

   if (hStore == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      return;

   memset (&StoreInfo, 0, sizeof (StoreInfo));
   StoreInfo.cbSize = sizeof(STOREINFO);
   if (!GetStoreInfo(hStore, &StoreInfo))
   {
      error = GetLastError();
   }

   // 1st part
   PartInfo[0].cbSize = sizeof(PartInfo[0]);
   hPartSearch = FindFirstPartition(hStore, &PartInfo[0]);
   // 2nd part
   PartInfo[1].cbSize = sizeof(PartInfo[1]);
   FindNextPartition(hPartSearch,&PartInfo[1]);


   // Format and remount boot partition
   hPart = OpenPartition(hStore, PartInfo[0].szPartitionName);
   bRes = DismountPartition(hPart);
   error = GetLastError();
   bRes = FormatPartition(hPart);
   error = GetLastError();
   bRes = MountPartition(hPart);
   error = GetLastError();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks timmf

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <storemgr.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain( int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[] )
{

 STOREINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cbSize = sizeof( STOREINFO );




 HANDLE hStore, hPartSearch, hPart;
   STOREINFO StoreInfo;
   PARTINFO PartInfo[3];
   DWORD error;
   BOOL bRes;

   hStore = OpenStore(L"DSK2:");

   if (hStore == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
 printf("Error opening store");
   }

   memset (&StoreInfo, 0, sizeof (StoreInfo));
   StoreInfo.cbSize = sizeof(STOREINFO);
   if (!GetStoreInfo(hStore, &StoreInfo))
   {
      error = GetLastError();
   }

   // 1st part
   PartInfo[0].cbSize = sizeof(PartInfo[0]);
   hPartSearch = FindFirstPartition(hStore, &PartInfo[0]);
   // 2nd part
   PartInfo[1].cbSize = sizeof(PartInfo[1]);
   FindNextPartition(hPartSearch,&PartInfo[1]);


   // Format and remount boot partition
   hPart = OpenPartition(hStore, PartInfo[0].szPartitionName);
   bRes = DismountPartition(hPart);
   error = GetLastError();
   bRes = FormatPartition(hPart);
   error = GetLastError();
   bRes = MountPartition(hPart);
   error = GetLastError();
}
```